# background picture slideshow with fade

Tags: html, css

I would like to change between background pictures. I wish to use fade in and out. When picture is up, I want it to stay with 100% opacity for some time. Currently I have problems how to figure out how this can be done, and the opacity is like a walking missile.

I have this ( save space but know I should use webkit and moz as well). It works, but it looks like as soon as the opacity is 100% it begin to decrease, - I would like it to stay at those 100% for x time for each picture, and the fade effect should be pretty fast:

```
.banner ul.kf-slider li {
    animation: fade-out 24s infinite both;
    background-image: url(images/photo1.jpg); 
}
@media (min-width: 58em) {
   .banner ul.kf-slider li {
        background-image: url(images/photo1.jpg); 
   } 
}
.banner ul.kf-slider li:nth-child(2) {
    background-image: url(images/photo2.jpg);
    animation-delay: 8s; 
}
@media (min-width: 58em) {
    .banner ul.kf-slider li:nth-child(2) {
        background-image: url(images/photo2.jpg); 
    } 
}
.banner ul.kf-slider li:nth-child(3) {
    background-image: url(images/photo3.jpg);
    animation-delay: 16s; 
}
@media (min-width: 58em) {
    .banner ul.kf-slider li:nth-child(3) {
    background-image: url(images/photo3.jpg); } 
}

@keyframes fade-in {
     0% {  opacity: 0; }
     100% { opacity: 1; } 
    }
}

@keyframes fade-out {
     33% {   opacity: 1; }
     66% {  opacity: 0; } 
}
```

html code:

```
<section class="banner">
    <!--List items for bg images -->
    <ul class="kf-slider">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: It would be great format css code and enclose html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some generic issues

- your media queries where not making any changes so i have removed them.
- you were not using the `fadi-in` animation so i removed it
- you had some extra `}` which i removed

Since you are using a single animation (*you have to, since you are animating the same property*) you need to time the animation along the whole duration of the animation (*the time it takes for all images to fade in / out*)

So you animation would be something like this

- All start with opacity 0
- slide fades in for 2 seconds and remains opaque for 6 seconds and fades out for another 2 second
- the 2 seconds of fade out coincide with the 2 seconds of fade in of the next slide

So since you want 24 seconds for the whole slideshow (*should be called fadeshow since we are not sliding anything*) each 1 second of the keyframes is 4.1666% of the whole duration.

```
@keyframes fade-out {
  0% {opacity: 0;} /*start fading in*/
  8.333%{opacity:1} /*complete the fade in in 2 seconds*/
  33.333%{opacity:1} /*remain at opacity 1 until 8 seconds*/
  41.666% {opacity: 0;} /*fade out until 10 seconds*/
}
```

---

Full example

```css
.banner ul.kf-slider {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.banner ul.kf-slider li {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity:0;
  
  animation: fade-out 24s infinite;
  background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/300x200&text=Image1);
}
.banner ul.kf-slider li:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/300x200&text=Image2);
  animation-delay: 8s;
}
.banner ul.kf-slider li:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/300x200&text=Image3);
  animation-delay: 16s;
}
@keyframes fade-out {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  8.333%{opacity:1}
  33.333%{opacity:1}
  41.666% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<section class="banner">
  <!--List items for bg images -->
  <ul class="kf-slider">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Was a big problem all day long. If possible, is it straight forward to add different text for each picture? Just looking for a hint, not necessarily a big solution again lol.

Comment: @HansPede the text the shows is dummy text. You could add text inside the `li` elements and style it anyway you like. (*and of course use your own images, these are just for illustration of the technique*)